# Inno Setup Registry entry for custom URL protocol

Tags: url, protocols, inno-setup

I'm hoping someone can help me translate the following into a correctly formatted InnoSetup [Registry] entry to use in my InnoSetup Installer? The goal here is to create a new custom URL protocol on the user's machine.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT      
       ctp
          (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
          URL Protocol = ""
          DefaultIcon
               (Default) = "myapp.exe"
          shell
               open
                    command
                         (Default) = "C:\Program Files\MyApp\myapp.exe"
```

I read through the InnoSetup Help doc but couldn't figure out how to translate the above into a proper InnoSetup Registry section:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".....etc.
```

The final result after the installer runs is that the user clicks on a link on a web site formatted as "ctp://myapp.exe" and that local app will launch on the user's machine. Am I approaching this correctly?
Thanks very much for any responses.

Comment: Essentiually, you need to add a single `[Registry]` entry for each value. The nesting is irrelevant and you just need to specify the full key path to each value in the `Key:` section. See this [FAQ entry](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#assoc) for an example.

Comment: Also, don't forget to use `%1` in your [`shell command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx#app_reg) value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "ctp"; ValueType: "string"; ValueData: "URL:Custom Protocol"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "ctp"; ValueType: "string"; ValueName: "URL Protocol"; ValueData: ""
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "ctp\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: "string"; ValueData: "{app}\YourApp.exe,0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "ctp\shell\open\command"; ValueType: "string"; ValueData: """{app}\YourApp.exe"" ""%1"""
```

Comment: Answer provided by TLama works perfectly! Thanks so much. I have one further question. Is there a way to check to see if a local file exists using javascript in a web page? I don't need to launch the app, I just need to check to see if it exists prior to calling the new URL protocol, and if it doesn't prompt the user to download it.

Comment: You're welcome! If it resolved your question, then you might consider to [`accept it this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541). To your additional question. This ask as a separate question, please (to be honest, I wouldn't even be able to answer you since I don't know JavaScript). Thanks and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

@TLama's answer is correct, but might not work for everybody.

`HKCU` is actually a merge between `HKLM\Software\Classes` and `HKCU\Software\Classes` and writting to `HKCU` *directly* **may** require administrative access on some systems, thus it's not compatible with InnoSetup's `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`. The official [`HKCU`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key) documentation explains:

> If you write keys to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, the system stores
> the information under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes. If you
> write values to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and the key already
> exists under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes, the system will store
> the information there instead of under
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.

The alternative is `HKA` (see [`[Registry]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection)) which resolves to `HKLM` in administrative installs and `HKCU` in non-administrative ones. The documentation also states that:

> HKCU and HKA should only be used for settings which are compatible
> with roaming profiles.
>
> Using HKCR is not recommended, use HKA with the Subkey parameter set
> to "Software\Classes" instead.

So, if you care about non-administrative installs, your `[Registry]` section should look like this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\ctp"; ValueType: "string"; ValueData: "URL:Custom Protocol"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\ctp"; ValueType: "string"; ValueName: "URL Protocol"; ValueData: ""
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\ctp\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: "string"; ValueData: "{app}\myapp.exe,0"
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\ctp\shell\open\command"; ValueType: "string"; ValueData: """{app}\myapp.exe"" ""%1"""
```

For more info see the links above, and also the following ones:

- InnoSetup - [Creating File Associations](https://jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#assoc)
- InnoSetup - [Non Administrative Install Mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=admininstallmode)
- Microsoft - [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)